# How to work with multiple types in single collection with mgo

Tags: mongodb, go, mgo

I'm very new to golang and try to write a simple event-sourcing user-management webapi using mongodb as backing database. Now i have User, which looks something like this:

```
type User struct {
Id       bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
UserName string        `json:"username" bson:"username"`
Email    string        `json:"email" bson:"email"`
PwdHash  string        `json:"pwd_hash" bson:"pwd_hash"`
FullName string        `json:"fullname" bson:"fullname"`
}
```

and three events, happening to user, when somebody uses api:

```
type UserCreatedEvent struct {
    UserId         bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    //time when event was issued
    CreatedEpoch   time.Time     `json:"created_epoch" bson:"created_epoch"`
    //id of user that made a change
    IssuedByUserId bson.ObjectId `json:"issuedby_userid" bson:"issuedby_userid"`
}

type UserDeletedEvent struct {
    UserId         bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    CreatedEpoch   time.Time     `json:"created_epoch" bson:"created_epoch"`
    //id of user that made a change
    IssuedByUserId bson.ObjectId `json:"issuedby_userid" bson:"issuedby_userid"`
}

type UserUpdatedEvent struct {
    UserId         bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    CreatedEpoch   time.Time     `json:"created_epoch" bson:"created_epoch"`
    //id of user that made a change
    IssuedByUserId bson.ObjectId `json:"issuedby_userid" bson:"issuedby_userid"`
    ChangedFieldName     string  `json:"changed_field_name" bson:"changed_field_name"`
    NewChangedFieldValue string  `json:"new_changed_field_value" bson:"new_changed_field_value"`
}
```

Now i'm stuck on saving and retrieving events from db. The problem is i want to store them in a single collection, so that i have a full plain history of user modifications. But i can't find how to correctly store event type name as a mongo document field and then use it in searches. What is the idiomatic go-way to do this?

I'll be gratefull for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's nice about a non-relational database is that a little redundancy is OK and is faster for retrieval since you're not joining things together. You could just add your bottom three objects as properties on your `User` in whatever fashion makes sense for you and your data. Then you wouldn't need to store the `UserId` on those objects either.

If you need to search over the `Events` quickly, you could create another collection to hold them. You'd be inserting to two collections, but retrieval times/logic should be pretty good/easy to write.

Your new `Event` would be something like:

```
type UserEventType int

const (
    Created UserEventType = iota
    Deleted
    Updated
)

type UserEvent struct {
    UserId               bson.ObjectId `json:"id" bson:"_id"`
    CreatedEpoch         time.Time     `json:"created_epoch" bson:"created_epoch"`
    //id of user that made a change
    IssuedByUserId       bson.ObjectId `json:"issuedby_userid" bson:"issuedby_userid"`
    ChangedFieldName     string        `json:"changed_field_name,omitempty" bson:"changed_field_name,omitempty"`
    NewChangedFieldValue string     `json:"new_changed_field_value,omitempty" bson:"new_changed_field_value,omitempty"`
    EventType            UserEventType `json:"user_event_type" bson:"user_event_type"`
}
```

Notice the `omitempty` on the fields that are optional depending on the type of event.

You really aren't supposed to store different objects in the same collection. Here's a line from the Mongo documentation:

> MongoDB stores documents in collections. Collections are analogous to tables in relational databases.

In case you aren't familiar with relational databases, a table would essentially represent one type of object.

Comment: thanks for your reply!
Well, that's quity similar to what i wanted to implement. The question is the same: how do i retrieve history for, say, some period of time? I'll have to search in 3 array properties and that'll be not so fast as searching in one, won't it? That's why i moved from RDBMS to NoSQL.

Comment: You could store those objects separately then, but you should be doing it in a different collection for each object. The approach you have in your questions more resembles a RDBMS than a document-based store. Can you explain further why you felt you needed to make that transition?

Comment: Main problem with RDBMS for me was write (insert) efficiency. I plan to implement new versions of microservices using Go+Mongo and most of them must handle 10k+ inserts per second, where most of inserts are these events, stored as history of changes of some objects, which then are included in some reports (most of them are weekly/daily, but users also can make a report for period of time). Based on my experience, RDBMS are quite slow here and they don't give these schema-less freedom. So, my main idea was to store this differently-typed objects in single collection with, maybe, epoch-based id.

Comment: Just keep in mind that collections should only hold one type of object. What if you did two collections, one for `Users` and one for `Events`? The `User` will have the structure I proposed in my answer, and then `Event` could have all the fields you need among the three different types + a `Type` field to let you know why kind of event it is. This way you always get the events for a user, and you can search among the events for certain ones quickly.

Comment: That's exactly what i wanted to do! But i don't understand, how can i put struct type into Type field in mongo (using mgo or some other go-way). Do i need to manually fill these Type field in go struct?